# OpenApi specification generator - Supply values from multiple Enum classes for a String field

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-mvc, openapi-generator

I'm writing a Spring Boot application in Kotlin, and I'm currently struggling to generate a specification for a DTO class that has a backing field of the type `String`, which I want to then later parse into one of two enum classes in the adapter layer.

I've tried the following approach using the `oneOf` Annotation value, which seemed like it does what I want:

```kotlin
data class MyDto(
    @Schema(
        type = "string",
        oneOf = [MyFirstEnum::class, MySecondEnum::class]
    )
    val identifier: String,
    val someOtherField: String
) {
    fun transform() { ... } // this will use the string identifier to pick the correct enum type later
}
```

Which results in the following OpenApi Spec:

```json
"MyDto": {
    "required": [
        "someOtherField",
        "identifier"
    ],
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "identifier": {
            "type": "object",    // <--- this should be string
            "oneOf": [{
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "FirstEnumValue1",
                        "FirstEnumValue2",
                        "FirstEnumValue3"
                    ]
                }, {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "SecondEnumValue1",
                        "SecondEnumValue2",
                        "SecondEnumValue3"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "someOtherField": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the enum constants are (I think) correctly inlined into the specification, but the `type` annotation on the field, which I set to `string` is bypassed, resulting in an `object` type, which I suppose is incorrect in this case.

My questions are:

- Is my current code and the resulting spec valid with the `object` declaration instead of `string`?
- Is there a better way to embed the enum values into the spec?

**Edited to add:** I'm using Spring Boot v2.7.8 in combination with `springdoc-openapi` v1.6.13 to automatically generate the OpenApi Spec.

Comment: The resulting spec is not valid, it's supposed to be `type: string`. This looks like a bug in the library that generates an OpenAPI spec from the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation based approach that I showed in my question does not seem to generate a valid OpenApi spec with `springdoc-openapi:1.6.13`. The type of the field `identifier` needs to be String, as Helen mentioned in the comments.

I was able to solve the issue by creating the Schema for this particular class manually, using a `GlobalOpenApiCustomizer` Bean:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun myDtoCustomizer(): GlobalOpenApiCustomizer {
    val firstEnum = StringSchema()
    firstEnum.description = "First Enum"
    MyFirstEnum.values().forEach { firstEnum.addEnumItem(it.name) }

    val secondEnum = StringSchema()
    secondEnum.description = "Second Enum"
    MySecondEnum.values().forEach { secondEnum.addEnumItem(it.name) }

    return GlobalOpenApiCustomizer {
        it.components.schemas[MyDto::class.simpleName] = ObjectSchema()
            .addProperty(
                MyDto::identifier.name,
                StringSchema().oneOf(
                    listOf(
                        firstEnum,
                        secondEnum
                    )
                )
            )
            .addProperty(MyDto::someOtherField.name, StringSchema())
    }
}
```

Which in turn produces the following Spec:

```json
"MyDto": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "identifier": {
            "type": "string",
            "oneOf": [{
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "First Enum",
                    "enum": [
                        "FirstEnumValue1",
                        "FirstEnumValue2",
                        "FirstEnumValue3"
                    ]
                }, {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Second Enum",
                    "enum": [
                        "SecondEnumValue1",
                        "SecondEnumValue2",
                        "SecondEnumValue3"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "someOtherField": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```